# Process fork in linux

Tags: c, fork

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<unistd.h>

int main(){ 
pid_t pid;
int num_coconuts = 17;
pid = fork();

if(pid == 0) { 
    num_coconuts = 42; 
    exit(0); 
} else { 
    wait(NULL);  }
}

printf("I see %d coconuts!\n", num_coconuts);
exit(0);
}
```

The result is "I see 17 coconuts". Why num_coconuts did not change when pid == 0 ?

Comment: It did. For the child. You just exit immediately from the child.

Comment: It's mean that num_coconuts has value 42 for the child and num_coconuts has value 17 for the parent. And last, it printed the value of num_coconuts's parent?

Comment: yes, that's what it means. The parent is the only process that can possibly reach the print statement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's observe what your code does:

1. You set `num_coconuts = 17`.
2. You fork and get a new process.
3. You check if a process is the child (`pid == 0)` or if it is the parent (`pid != 0`).
4. In the child process you set `num_coconuts = 42` but then you immediately exit.
5. You print `num_coconuts`

As you can see your child process can never reach 5. because you exit in step 4. Delete the `exit()` and you will get the two coconuts.

Comment: If i delete the exit(), it will print the same result

Comment: @MartinHoang - No it won't. It will print twice. For the parent and for the child.

Comment: @StoryTeller I see